# Merging Deferred Observerables Udp

Tags: c#, system.reactive, udpclient

I'm trying to merge a set of deferred observable (which originate from UDP.RecieveAsync) calls into one observable I can subscribe too. I'm new to Reactive Extensions and I'm sure I'm doing something wrong with the deffering.

```
Log.Information("InboundUdpListener is starting");

IObservable<UdpReceiveResult> receiveStream = null;

IList<IObservable<UdpReceiveResult>> receivingStreams = new List<IObservable<UdpReceiveResult>>();

foreach (var devicePortMapping in _deviceTypeMapper.GetDeviceTypes())
{
      Log.Information("InboundUdpListener is starting for DeviceType: {DeviceType}, Port: {Port}",
      devicePortMapping.DeviceType, devicePortMapping.Port);

      var client = new UdpClient(devicePortMapping.Port);

      receivingStreams.Add(Observable.Defer(() => client
          .ReceiveAsync()
          .ToObservable())
          .Repeat());

      _clients.Add(client);
}

receiveStream = receivingStreams.Merge();

_listener = receiveStream.Subscribe(async r =>
{
    Log.Information("InboundUdpListener received {BytesReceived} bytes from IPAddress : {IPAddress}, Port : {Port}", r.Buffer.Length, r.RemoteEndPoint.Address.MapToIPv4(),r.RemoteEndPoint.Port);

    var message = new IncomingMessage(r.RemoteEndPoint, r.Buffer);

    var deviceTypeMap = _deviceTypeMapper.GetDeviceType(message);

    message.DeviceType = deviceTypeMap?.DeviceType ?? DeviceTypeEnum.UnIdentified;

    Log.Information("InboundUdpListener is publishing message {@Message}", message);

    await _messagePublisher.Publish(message);
});

Log.Information("InboundUdpListener is started");
```

Comment: What part are you having a problem with?

Comment: You not actually merging your observables by calling merge inside your loop. You just creating a single observable every iteration. What you want to do is pass all the observables you create in the loop to merge at the end to create a single merged observable.

Comment: OK I'll go back to that idea, I tried that out earlier but I couldn't get the syntax right. I'm wondering with the collection of cold observables do they get subscribed to when I subscribe to the merged observable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are definitely thinking in a procedural manner, rather than functional.

You need to try to keep your processing within the observable and avoid `foreach` and temporary lists of observables.

You are also using a `UdpClient` to produce your values - this object is disposable so your observable should manage its lifetime for you. You do that with `Observable.Using`.

Also, async methods can be consumed with `Observable.FromAsync` so you should be using that too.

So, given all of that your `receiveStream` should probably look like this:

```
IObservable<UdpReceiveResult> receiveStream =
    from devicePortMapping in _deviceTypeMapper.GetDeviceTypes().ToObservable()
    from stream in
        Observable
            .Using(
                () => new UdpClient(devicePortMapping.Port),
                client =>
                    Observable
                        .FromAsync(() => client.ReceiveAsync())
                        .Repeat())
    select stream;
```

Now, given what I see in in your subscribe call, you probably can go one step further and do this:

```
IObservable<UdpReceiveResult> receiveStream =
    from devicePortMapping in _deviceTypeMapper.GetDeviceTypes().ToObservable()
    from stream in
        Observable
            .Using(
                () => new UdpClient(devicePortMapping.Port),
                client =>
                    Observable
                        .FromAsync(() => client.ReceiveAsync())
                        .Repeat())
    select new IncomingMessage(stream.RemoteEndPoint, stream.Buffer)
    {
        DeviceType = devicePortMapping
    };
```

This now means that you have access to the original device type in the query itself, so no need to look it up - if I have correctly understood what your code is doing.

If you do need to do the look up then you should do it as part of the query. Try doing it this way:

```
IObservable<UdpReceiveResult> receiveStream =
    from devicePortMapping in _deviceTypeMapper.GetDeviceTypes().ToObservable()
    from stream in
        Observable
            .Using(
                () => new UdpClient(devicePortMapping.Port),
                client =>
                    Observable
                        .FromAsync(() => client.ReceiveAsync())
                        .Repeat())
    from message in Observable.Start(() =>
    {
        var message = new IncomingMessage(r.RemoteEndPoint, r.Buffer);
        var deviceTypeMap = _deviceTypeMapper.GetDeviceType(message);
        message.DeviceType = deviceTypeMap?.DeviceType ?? DeviceTypeEnum.UnIdentified;
    })
    select message;
```

It's probably best to use the second query if you can.

Comment: I see what you mean, this look awesome, RX really is a game changer for me and I see so many uses for it in projects I'm going. Just need to break some of the previous mental model and patterns that I'm used to. I'll try implementing this and come back to upvote.

Comment: @JohnKattenhorn - No trouble. I must agree that it is a game changer. There are so many times now that I just simply avoid the standard event and the now-standard async model and just use observables. They are flexible and extremely powerful. The hard part is sometimes working out how the query should look, but once you get it it is a beautiful thing to behold.

Comment: This code has served me well but I've run into some issues with it which I've documented over here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/110608/rx-udpclient-that-listeners-for-messages-from-devices-from-a-list-of-ports-and-s

Answer (score 1):

You not actually merging your observables by calling merge inside your loop. You just creating a single observable every iteration. What you want to do is pass all the observables you create in the loop to merge at the end to create a single merged observable.

EDIT: Turned my comment above into an answer.